# Preinitialised NSArray indicates count is zero?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to debug an issue, whereby the NSArray I have created shows that it has zero elements.

```
NSArray *libPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"libcustomx.2" ofType:@"dylib"],
            INSTALL_PATH,
            [@"~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/libcustomx.2.dylib" stringByExpandingTildeInPath],
            @"/usr/lib/libcustomx.2.dylib",
            nil];

NSUInteger count = libPaths.count
```

This is Objective-C code from a project that was originally designed to build on MacOS X 10.6 and I am now trying to get it to build on MacOS X 10.11, using Xcode 7.2.1. Not being very experienced with Objective-C, I am not sure what could be causing a new array to be zero length at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no file in the app bundle named libcustomx.2.dylib then the first value will be `nil` and the array will be empty.

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the case. If I put the app bundle at the end of the list, such that it may result in 'nil, nil', if the bundle is nil, would that be okay?

Comment: That would be fine if it meets your needs.